# Is there any difference between these two "if" conditional statement?

Tags: c#, if-statement

First if condition

```
if(Txt1.Text != "" && Txt2.Text != "")
```

Second if condition

```
if((Txt1.Text && Txt2.Text) != "")
```

Is there any diff between these two conditional statement?

Comment: Will C# even compile the second one? I wouldn't think so as you are trying to do a boolean `and` operation on two string values.

Comment: Did you mean in the second one to string concatenation? if((Txt1.Text + Txt2.Text) != "")

Comment: @Elisha not a string concatenation!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. The second one is attempting to `&&` two strings, and compare the result to the empty string. I don't believe this is valid C#, as no `&&` operator overload exists for two strings.

I appreciate your desire for terseness, but the first one is really what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Um, the second one is mal-typed and is rejected by the compiler?

Answer (score 3):

First, as Blair Conrad stated, `if((Txt1.Text && Txt2.Text) != "")` will not compile as you cannot do a boolean `and` operation on two strings. However, if you are asking whether `if((Txt1.Text + Txt2.Text) != "")` is more efficient than the first operation, I would say that it probably is not more efficient for the simple reason that `Txt1.Text + Txt2.Text` will first create a new string and then compare it against the empty string. Granted, we are probably talking about a difference in nanoseconds.

Regardless, you should use `string.IsNullOrEmpty` on each of the strings because it makes your intent clearer.

Comment: Nice point about the Txt1.Text + Txt2.Text. On the other hand, `string.IsNullOrEmpty` isn't necessarily a drop-in replacement - sometimes we really are looking specifically for empty strings. Perhaps `null` stands for uninitialized, and any non-empty value is valid. Although I agree with @Thomas that it's worth using whenever it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

you cant do the second one.  the first one is correct.

Answer (score 1):

the 2nd one is not accepted by the compiler. because the string type can't be compared with boolean type.

Comment: `&&` needs not be restricted to boolean arguments; just like `+` is not restricted to arithmetic types.

Answer (score 0):

```
if((Txt1.Text && Txt2.Text) != "")
```

While boolean logic does have [associative properties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_logic#Properties) for the `&&` and `||` operators, it does not apply to the equality operator, which is what it looks like you're trying to do here:

```
(a && b) != ""  -- doesn't translate to --> a != "" && b != ""
```

Equality, is defined in [first-order logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Equality_and_its_axioms) as being [reflexive (a=a), symmetric (a=b, b=a) and transitive (a=b, b=c, a=c)](http://www.mathwords.com/e/equation_rules.htm), but not associative.

Alternatively, if you think about it from the compiler's perspective, parentheses have a [higher precedence](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/CSharpOperatorPrecedence.aspx) than the equality operator.  So, when the compiler evaluates the expression `(Txt1.Text && Txt2.Text) != ""`, it first evaluates what's inside of the parentheses, and then does the equality check.

Comment: I think you confused transitive and symmetric.